# How to make Go search for imports beyond GOROOT

Tags: go, goimports

I'm migrating dep project into go modules, and some Go files in this project import proto files, but when I execute `go mod tidy`, it says that cannot find the package where proto files are. Project's structure:

```
version_service
   proto
     authentication
       authentication.proto
     version
       version.proto
 repository.go
```

I'm importing like this in repository.go

```
pb "proto/version"
```

And i have this:

```
proto/version: package proto/version is not in GOROOT
```

How import this files?

Comment: First thing, you must _never_ keep any packages under `$GOROOT`—that is for the Go's own source code; yours must be located in either of the so-called workspaced listed in the contents of the `GOPATH` env. variable. See [this](https://golang.org/doc/gopath_code.html#Organization). Also note that in this day and age you should probably be switching to [`go mod`](https://blog.golang.org/migrating-to-go-modules).

Comment: Sorry, I must have expressed myself badly, but my package is not into GOROOT, and i'm migrating to go modules, but this problem is happening exactly when i execute go mod init, the syntax that i'm using to import proto path is wrong?

Comment: `proto/version` is not a valid import path. Use the full path, for example, `github.com/version_service/proto/version`.

Comment: @Flimzy i think the problem is that Go is searching for the package in GOROOT, because before i use "proto/version", i was importing with the full path, and i was getting the same error. Is it possible to make Go looking for imports in another folder beyond GOROOT?

Comment: As others have said, packages never go under `$GOROOT` anyway. If you're getting the same error, it means you're still using an invalid import path. It's also possible that your module is misnamed, so that Go doesn't know to resolve those import paths to the local module. Please update your question with the full path you've used, and the contents of `go.mod`.

Comment: @Flimzy I made confusion, actually the problem happens when i execute `go mod tidy`. After you said to me review the import path, i fixed, and what happening is that Go understand that is a remote import path and i got 'time out', but this package is local. How solve that?

Comment: You must stil use the full import path. There are no relative or "local" imports in Go.

Comment: Well, if a command related to working with modules times out, try passing `-x` to its invocation to see what actions it carries out under its hood. To move further, we must have more details about your setup, and hence this whole discussion seems to be unfit for the SO format—I invite you to post to [the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-nuts) or [`r/golang`](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/) instead. Still, if you convert a project making use of 3rd-party packages, you either need to convert them to modules first—or check whether their upstreams already did that…

Comment: …(which is pretty likely) or _vendor_ these packages within your own package. If the 3rd-party packages are available as downloadable modules, just let `go mod download` fetch them; if this operation times out, that's probably a netwok problem, and those modules are not "local", you know. If you really trying to tell about truly local packages _(local to your program, that is)_ then just use full import paths, as @Flimzy said—nothing should be attempted to be download.

Comment: @kostix thanks for your response. The scenario is, i have a project, and in this project there are four services, distribuited in four differents folders. For each service there is a proto folder where the proto files are,but this services were created with dep, so i'm migrating all this services into Go modules. For now, i want to execute `go mod tidy` in a particular service to finish the process to turning it into a module, but i'm getting error with a proto file import in the repository.go file, so i'm following the tips about turning proto folder into a module.

Comment: OK, let's try to dumb things down: if you have a directory named `version_service` somewhere, and _in_ it there's a file named `go.mod` which begins with something like `module acme.com/foo/bar`, the import path you must be using in the code of `repository.go` is `"acme.com/foo/bar/proto/version"`. If the `go.mod` file is located higher up in a directory hierarchy—so that the `version_service` directory is one or more levels deeper than where `go.mod` is located, add all the intermediate directories to the import path. IOW, the import path in the `go.mod` is sort of a "root path", if you like.

Answer (score -1):

GOROOT is meant to "store" Go native packages, so you **shouldn't** use it for your own packages, instead, you need to use [Go Modules](https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/create-module).

You can interpret Go Modules almost like a native package manager for your Go projects, for example, in your project with the following structure:

```
version_service
  proto
   authentication
     authentication.proto
   version
     version.proto
  repository.go
```

In you shell you can start the Go Modules with `go mod init package.name`, in your case *package.name* could be *proto*, so using your project root as reference you could import packages using *proto/version*

```
package authentication

import (
   pb "proto/version"
)

func main() {
    pb.Foo().Bar()

}
```